# Blocking Proxies from Views

Tags: php, ajax, proxy, block

I was just wondering...Other than using User Agent OR Google Analytics, is there any good way to detect proxies? IE people using proxy bots to visit your site? Is there a way to do this in JS?

I've already tried pulling data from Google Analytics using gAPI but it isn't useful since i'd have to make more then 50,000 requests a day and is simply not feasible.

Purpose is because i'm running an ad-management website and wish to stop bots...

How does Adsense manage to block all those China bots from Adsense profit generating?

Would appreciate if there's any thoughts regarding this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service like Maxmind to do this.

Details : http://www.maxmind.com/en/proxy